# in zend, how to check by ID that a session exists?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, google-maps

i am using google maps with xml data,
the way google maps works is that it calls my server to get the xml(i have to pass it an url, i can't pass the xml to google),

since all my pages are user/password protected, 
i need to implement some sort of authentication for google maps, so i was thinking of passing it the current user session id(encrypted in some way) so that when google calls my script, i can check that a session with that id exists, thus google is calling me on behalf of that user

Comment: how are you storing your sessions?

Comment: don't know, the default way zend stores them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using my own table to save the session and then execute queries on it

in bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initSession()
    {

         $this->bootstrap('cache')
        $config = array(
            'name'              => 'session', //table name as per Zend_Db_Table
            'primary'           => array(
                'session_id',   //the sessionID given by PHP
                'save_path',    //session.save_path
                'name',         //session name
                //'cols' => array('session_id', 'save_path', 'name', 'modified', 'lifetime', 'session_data')
            ),
            'primaryAssignment' => array(
                //you must tell the save handler which columns you
                //are using as the primary key. ORDER IS IMPORTANT
                'sessionId', //first column of the primary key is of the sessionID
                'sessionSavePath', //second column of the primary key is the save path
                'sessionName', //third column of the primary key is the session name
            ),
            'modifiedColumn'    => 'modified',     //time the session should expire
            'dataColumn'        => 'session_data', //serialized data
            'lifetimeColumn'    => 'lifetime',     //end of life for a specific record
            'user_id' => 'user_id'
        );
        //Tell Zend_Session to use your Save Handler
        $savehandler = new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($config);


        //http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable
        //cookie persist for 30 min
        $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');


        $seconds = $config->session->seconds_life;
        //Zend_Session::rememberMe($seconds = ($config->session->seconds_life));
        //make the session persist for 30 min
        $savehandler->setLifetime($seconds)
            ->setOverrideLifetime(true);

        Zend_Session::setSaveHandler($savehandler);

        Zend_Session::start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`session_id()` will give you the [session id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) of the current request. You could attempt to send this to Google as a cookie, remember that for this to work Google will have to accept your cookies. If it does not then you'll have to find a different way

Comment: you mean try to steal a cookie from my site and inject it to google bymyself :D, umm i don't know, doesn't inspire trust on the long term

Comment: the `session_id` is public - you'd be giving away nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the method of the Zend Session class.

```
$sessionId = Zend_Session::getId();
```

Comment: this won't work because google gets automatically a new session id, since zend assigns one even to users that didn't authenticate